# AngelCharp парсинг текста из тегов с одинаковым классом (C#)

Tags: c#, html, парсер, классы

Имеется примерно такой кусок страницы

```
<table cellspacing="0" id="work_outline">
  <tr>
      <th>Genre</th>
      <td>
        <div class="main_genre">
                    <a href="https://не_палю_ссылку">Ненужная инфа 1</a>
                    <a href="https://не_палю_ссылку">Ненужная инфа 2</a>
                    <a href="https://не_палю_ссылку">Ненужная инфа 3</a>
                    <a href="https://не_палю_ссылку">...</a>
                    <a href="https://не_палю_ссылку">Ненужная инфа n</a>                    
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  
          <tr>
    <th>File size</th>
    <td>
      <div class="main_genre">
                              330.86MB
                        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Оба тега div, оба с классом main_genre. Оба под table cellspacing="0" id="work_outline"

Как спарсить конкретно текст "330.86MB"?

Comment: Обычно таблицы статичны, не меняют свои колонки, а значит вы смело можете сделать `найденныеDiv[1].Text();`. Можете пойти иначе, найти отличие, например `MB`, если оно есть в тексте, то значит вы нашли нужное, сделать это можно наример так: `.Where(x=>x.Text().Contains("MB"));`. Другой вариант, искать не `div`, а брать все `th`, потом найти тот, который имеет `File Size` текст и взять его соседа, из которого уже вытягивать текст.

Comment: Я так понимаю нет никакого способа парсить конкретный по счету тег с классом `main_genre`? Или парсить только первый или сразу все?

Comment: Ну смотрите, есть условно 2 уровня: уровень CSS селектора, это некий "язык", по которому вы выбираете нужный объект (условно `div.myClass#myId` == `<div class="myClass" id="myId">`); и уровень c# языка, в котором вы работаете со всем как с объектами, коллекциями и прочим. Вот на уровне селектора, индексов в их нормальном понимании нет, вы не можете написать `div[2]` допустим, НО, там есть "псевдо классы", которые могут по индексу вытянуть конкретный объект, например [:nth-child(2)](https://www.sitepoint.com/css-pseudo-classes-styling-elements-based-on-their-index/).

Comment: Правда не знаю как это реализовано в AngleSharp, если поддерживает, то можете попробовать через них вытянуть. Ну а C# и так думаю понятно, вытягиваете все, у вас на руках коллекция объектов, а дальше хоть по индексу, хоть через LINQ, хоть проходитесь циклом, это уже на ваше усмотрение.